# Computations using Javascript in Processmaker

Tags: javascript, processmaker

I'm new to ProcessMaker and we were tasked to practice on computational processing using Javascript in ProcessMaker.

So I looked up the documentation, and I tried creating a dynaform that computes the total when you input a price and quantity.

I pasted the code I had in the "javascript" section, but when I try to preview it it just loads forever.

This is the code that I used:

```
 function calculateTotal() {
   getField("sTotal").value = parseFloat(getValueById("basePrice")) - 
   parseFloat(getValueById("Qty"));
}

leimnud.event.add(getField("basePrice"), 'click', calculateTotal);
leimnud.event.add(getField("Qty"), 'click', calculateTotal);
```

Answers would be really appreciated thanks.

Comment: Are you sure calculateTotal is getting called? Try adding a console log inside it

Comment: i now think that what's is that i used "leimnud". what is the proper parameter to use?

Comment: http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.0/JavaScript_in_DynaForms#Tying_Code_to_Events see Setting an event handler

Comment: Leimnud is only for ProcessMaker 2.x. If you are using ProcessMaker 3, that would indeed throw an error. What are you getting back from the console? Any errors?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed as Ethan Presberg mentioned, the Leimnud framework is only supported up to ProcessMaker 2.x.

For ProcessMaker 3.x you can use JQuery to trigger the onclick event by adding a button control like this:

`$("#button1").find("button").on("click", calculateTotal();`

You can find more information about using JQuery with ProcessMaker 3.x's Dynaforms in our Wiki here: http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.2/JavaScript_Functions_and_Methods

Best regards,

Arturo A. Robles

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

In dyna form add two text boxes and button

```
@@quantity
@@price
@@getTotalPrice
```

Now paste below code in JavaScript section:

```
$('#getTotalPrice').find('button').on("click", getTotal());

function getTotal()
{
var quantity = $('#quantity').getValue();
var price = $('#price').getValue();
var total = quantity * price;
}

alert (total);
```

If you want to assign this value to variable then create another variable `totalPrice`

```
$('#totalPrice').setValue(total);
```

Hope you understand.